# device from free diskspace does not match-up to size from list block size

Tags: rhel, virtual-machine, kvm, fdisk, cfdisk

The device /dev/sda2 original space at 32GB, then I try to expand to 512GB as it is shown in lsblk but not in disk free listing still show 32GB.  I've rebooted the redhat 7.6 vm.

```
    $ df -h
    Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    /dev/sda2        32G  6.0G   26G  19% /
    devtmpfs         16G     0   16G   0% /dev
    tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
    tmpfs            16G  1.6G   15G  10% /run
    tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
    tmpfs            16G   32K   16G   1% /tmp
    /dev/sda1       497M  132M  366M  27% /boot
    /dev/sdb1        63G  2.1G   58G   4% /mnt/resource
    tmpfs           3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/1000


    $ lsblk
    NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
    fd0      2:0    1     4K  0 disk 
    sda      8:0    0   512G  0 disk 
    ├─sda1   8:1    0   500M  0 part /boot
    └─sda2   8:2    0 511.5G  0 part /
    sdb      8:16   0    64G  0 disk 
    └─sdb1   8:17   0    64G  0 part /mnt/resource
    sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom

    $cat /proc/partitions | grep sda2
       8        2  536357888 sda2

    # parted /dev/sda2
    GNU Parted 3.1
    Using /dev/sda2
    Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
    (parted) print                                                            
    Model: Unknown (unknown)
    Disk /dev/sda2: 549GB
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
    Partition Table: loop
    Disk Flags: 

    Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
     1      0.00B  549GB  549GB  xfs
```

I'm wondering If i missed any steps.

Comment: If the physical block device has expanded, but the filesystem within the partition has not grown, you could try `resize2fs`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must also resize the file system, not only the partition.

The partition has to be expanded first, then the file system. For shrinking, the order would be reverse.

For `xfs`, the command to extend the file system seems to be `xfs_growfs` - expand an XFS filesystem. The default action is to grow the file system to fill the available space on the partition.

For `ext` file systems, the command is `resize2fs`.

Comment: Was missing the xfs_growfs /dev/sda2 command.  Thanks.